# Jenkins nodelabel plugin where does .jpi come from?

Tags: jenkins, puppet

I am writing a puppet script that will automatically setup a jenkins instance with the nodelabel parameter plugins. It successfully downloads the .hpi but the plugin still doesn't work.

When I install it using the web UI I see that a working version has both .hpi and .jpi files. I can't find a link for a .jpi anywhere so I am guessing this is generated from the .hpi. I'd like to know if/how this is created during the automated install process so that I can mimic it in puppet.

Comment: I thought this was the problem with Puppet's installation of the git plugin.  It turns out you just need `git-client` too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The .jpi and .hpi files are just zip files (JPI = jenkins plug in, HPI = hudson plug in). If you put the .hpi in your plugins directory (probably /var/lib/jenkins/plugins) and restart Jenkins, it will install the plug in.

What I found was Jenkins-ci.org stores .hpi files, and installing this way will leave them as .hpi files. Installing through the gui changes them to .jpi.

You might also look at the one of the existing puppet modules for Jenkins.